# Variables based on window height behave unexpectedly on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

To determine the homepage "hero" style section's height, we use this neat little thing:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    // Image Section Height
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();

    $( '.fp1' ) .css({'height': windowHeight +'px'});

    $( window ).resize(function(){
        var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
        $( '.fp1' ) .css({'height': windowHeight +'px'});
    });
});
```

It works great, except on mobile. When you scroll up the page, the address bar (at least on Android) is visible, and when you scroll down the page, it slides away, causing the content to jump the height of the address bar if you change scrolling directions.

Does anybody know of a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I just stopped listening to the `.resize` function on mobile devices. Hopefully it's not a big deal, but for now it works and prevents the jumpiness.